# Formatting of string in pas file

Tags: string, delphi, string-concatenation

Is there a nice way to assign a string to a variable when it spans many lines?

The reason for this is I have some large SQL statements (which I want in the pas) but it's annoying like this

```
var
  sql : string;
begin
  sql := 'SELECT * ' +
         'FROM foo ' +
         'WHERE `this`=0';
```

That is annoying to copy and paste into terminal / another program because I have to remove the ' and ' + etc.

Is there a way to so something like...

```
var
  sql : string;
begin
  sql := ""SELECT *
         FROM foo
         WHERE `this`=0"";
```

So some way to assign a block of text/string with new lines without having to concat it.

Comment: I use TOAD with Delphi, and it has a cool feature that removes the code from the statement, or add's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there is no way of expressing strings in this way in SQL, I normally use the RegEx search and replace available in the Delphi IDE to format strings in the required way.

```
  SELECT *
  FROM foo
  WHERE `this`=0
```

[image: Regular expression replace dialog]

This replaces any line with the line enclosed in quotes, followed by `+ sLineBreak +`

```
  sql :=
      '  SELECT *' + sLineBreak +
      '  FROM foo' + sLineBreak +
      '  WHERE `this`=0' + sLineBreak +
```

I then just tidy up the last line:

```
  sql :=
      '  SELECT *' + sLineBreak +
      '  FROM foo' + sLineBreak +
      '  WHERE `this`=0';
```

Of course the same can be done with any preceding or trailing text, such as `qry.SQL.Add('\0');`

Comment: Accepted this answer as most easy to use, but alas no multi string support :(

Comment: in what sense does this answer the question you asked?

Answer (score 4):

Your question is:

> Can a Delphi string literal span multiple lines?

The answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of (at least not out of the box). Anyway, you might want to take a look at this:

[How to assign a multiline string value without quoting each line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872503/how-to-assign-a-multiline-string-value-without-quoting-each-line)

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the SQL in a component which has a TStrings property like TSQLQuery, but my solution for longer / complex statements is to keep an 'example' copy as a source code comment, which has actual parameters to make tests easier, and keep both version in sync.

Answer (score 1):

If you like the way C# does it (like I do), then don't forget to **vote for this QC report**:

http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=2012

It suggests to make your example look like this:

```
var
  sql : string;
begin
  sql := @'SELECT *
         FROM foo
         WHERE `this`=0';
```

Comment: Hmm, how would that be ambiguous? Am I missing something?

Comment: the whitespace is ambigous this matters not for the sql example, but in other contexts it would sucks and additionally it breaks backward compatability (but that another matter of course)

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).

Answer (score 1):

If you install [GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/) in Delphi, the IDE will automatically insert a `'+` after pressing >enter< if you're inside a string and haven't closed it yet.

Download link: http://www.gexperts.org/download.html